# Flask SQLAlchemy DB connections with MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using falsk SQLAlchemy with MYSQL with all default configuration(pool size and timeout)

I don't understand why do I get out of DB connections from the MYSQL DB?
My server is not that heavy loaded.

Can someone please explain how the flask sql alchemy get and release DB connections?

If I have a pool thread of 20 on my apache mod_wsgi server that means by theory that i can have 20 db connection opens all the time and that's it no?

How flask sql alchemy handle close and restore those connections.
Thanks

Comment: Did you enabled echo and echo_pool and checked the logs? What error you are getting?

Comment: I am using AWS RDS MYSQL. I got the error
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1040, 'Too many connections')

after upgrading the instance it stopped but I dont understand how come all the connections are busy since I don't have that load.
Do you know how flask SQLAlchemy is managing the connection pool?

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
import sqlalchemy

dbhost = 'localhost' #host name
dbuser = 'root' #mysql username
dbpass = 'admin' #mysql password
dbname = 'mytable' #database name

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://'+dbuser+':'+dbpass+'@'+dbhost ) # connect to server

DB_URI = 'mysql://' + dbuser + ':' + dbpass + '@' + dbhost + '/' +dbname
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=DB_URI

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Comment: This what I am doing this how i connect to the DB.

Comment: you can apply this configration on your code @zivziv77

Comment: But you are not passing `engine` anywhere. How is that supposed to work?